# Can't start Orbot

Tags: orbot

[image: Orbot Log]
My orbit stopped connecting to the web. I've reset it and it won't start anymore. I have tried reinstalling the application.

Comment: Did you edit the torrc? and where are you downloading the apks from?

Comment: We need more information rather than just a screenshot of some logs, nothing in those logs seems to indicate any problem, the required information would appear later on in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

#### I would not recommend downloading Orbot from ***ANYWHERE*** but the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.torproject.android).

The version of Orbot you're are using seems to be very old and most likely will not work at all. The place you probably acquired the APK from is unlikely to be safe at *all* since the app hasn't looked like this since 2016 (bearing in mind that it's 2017 when the question was posted).

The best course of action would be to uninstall the current version of Orbot you are using then go to the Google Play Store on your Android Phone and search for "Orbot". Select the first option and install. From now on, Orbot should work perfectly and should be updated automatically.

Comment: Fdroid is also fine, the Guardian Project run their own fdroid repos, so you can get it straight from them (they're preconfigured in fdroid)